# Issue in fetching iPhone contacts from iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6, xcode5

I am fetching iPhone contact list in my app.I have made one sample app for this and printed its value like that and it worked fine.

```
 ABAddressBookRef ab=ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *arrTemp=(NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);

    NSLog(@"Array===%@",arrTemp);

    NSMutableArray *arrContact=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0;i<[arrTemp count];i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dicContact=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSString *str=(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue([arrTemp objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        @try
        {
            [dicContact setObject:str forKey:@"name"];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            [dicContact release];
            continue;
        }
        [arrContact addObject:dicContact];
        [dicContact release];
    }

    NSLog(@"arrContact===%@",arrContact);
```

I also used one more code to try as other way around and it also worked fine to me in sample.

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        //NSLog(@"\n%@\n", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++)
        {
            NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);

            NSLog(@"phoneNumber======%@",phoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

They work fine on simulator but when I run these codes on the device then strangely sometimes they don't give the contact details but most of the times they run fine.**Is there anything wrong in my coding?**

When I use this demo code in my main app then this code is never responding.**Is there any permission or any setting I have to do in my device for different apps?**

Also,When I used  **`CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);`** to get number of people then its giving me value 11 but I have only used five contacts on my  simulator and when I used **`CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);`** then I am getting repeated values (to satisfy the count of 11 from 5 contacts).

**Can somebody tell me whats wrong going on here for me?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From iOS6 onwards you need the users permission to access the contacts from address book. You are not asking for permission also. May be due to that you are not getting contacts. This code i have used in my app(written by someone else)

```
 + (BOOL)getAccessPermission
{
    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_release(sema);
    }
    else
    { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }
    return accessGranted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was actually missing this part.I have to fetch mobile number in array which should be at specific place at which name is coming in another array but its changing when I used above code.Can you tell me how to get corresponding number of the user with its name.

Comment: Have you got any clue on my other issues I asked in my question?

Comment: I never used address book methods directly. I have used a wrapper [ABContactHelper](https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper). It is very easy to use. You dont have to bother about ABAddressBook c api's.

Comment: Anil, How to use this code.. i am facing same issue

Comment: @MssiOS what exactly your issue? its ObjectiveCe code. are using ObjC or Swift?